# Dynamic Selector Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

I have a dynamic selector expression that produces anonymous type. It's working fine in linq to objects, but in linq to entities, it throws:

**Attempt 1**

> NotSupportedException
>
> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

```
Expression<Func<User, T>> DynamicSelect<T>(T obj, ParameterExpression userParam)
{
    var newExpression = Expression.New(
        typeof(T).GetConstructor(typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments),
        userParam,
        Expression.Constant("X"),
        Expression.Constant("Y")
    );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<User, T>>(newExpression, userParam);
}

var userParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "u");
var obj = new { User = new User(), Address = string.Empty, Fax = string.Empty };
var arr = context.Set<T>()
    .Select(DynamicSelect(obj, userParam))
    .ToArray();
```

**Attempt 2**, If I create a custom type, it's working, but I don't want to, because I want to reuse this helper method without creating additional custom type for each entity, I want to be able to pass the type based on consumer.

```
public class Container
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
Expression<Func<User, T>> DynamicSelect<T>(T obj, ParameterExpression userParam)
{
    var initExpression = Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(T)),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(T).GetProperty("User"), userParam),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(T).GetProperty("Address"), Expression.Constant("X")),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(T).GetProperty("Fax"), Expression.Constant("Y"))
    );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<User, T>>(initExpression, userParam);
}

var userParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "u");
var arr = context.Set<T>()
    .Select(DynamicSelect<Container>(null, userParam))
    .ToArray();
```

**Attempt 3**, I also tried using `Tuple<User, string, string>`, but it's not supported too.

> NotSupportedException
>
> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Tuple`3[User,System.String,System.String]
>   Create[User,String,String](User, System.String, System.String)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
Expression<Func<User, T>> DynamicSelect<T>(T obj, ParameterExpression userParam)
{
    var createExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Tuple), 
        "Create", 
        typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments,
        userParam,
        Expression.Constant("X"), 
        Expression.Constant("Y"));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<User, T>>(createExpression, userParam);
}

var userParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "u");
var arr = context.Set<User>()
    .Select(DynamicSelect<Tuple<User, string, string>>(null, userParam))
    .ToArray();
```

Please help.

**update**

I was trying to reuse this helper method in any consumer (User, Customer, Associate, etc) without having specific implementation to each consumer.

The class structure look like.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ContactDto Contact { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public ContactDto Contact { get; set; }
}
public class ContactDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    // other contact informations
}
```

And I have many contacts that could be different for each consumer.

```
var users = context.Set<User>()
    .Select(x => new UserDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        UserName = x.UserName,
        Contact = new ContactDto
        {
            Email = x.Contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "Email").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault()
        }
    })
    .ToArray();

var customers = context.Set<Customer>()
    .Select(x => new CustomerDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        CompanyName = x.CompanyName,
        Contact = new ContactDto
        {
            Address = x.Contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "Address").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
            Fax = x.Contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "Fax").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
        }
    })
    .ToArray();
```

And have refactored the `x.Contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "Address").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault()` into expression, but I can't use it directly inside the method like:

```
var users = context.Set<User>()
    .Select(x => new UserDto
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        UserName = x.UserName,
        Contact = new ContactDto
        {
            Email = GetContactExpression("Email").Compile()(x)
        }
    })
    .ToArray();
```

It will throw error because `Invoke` method is not supported in linq to expression, so that I need to refactored the whole `Select` expression, but I need to make it generic (`User` has `UserName`, but `Customer` has `CompanyName`, and any other information) and probably passing the contact type(s) too after this get solved. The expected result at the moment would be something lile:

```
var obj = new { User = new User(), Email = "" };
var users = context.Set<User>()
    .Select(x => DynamicSelect(obj))
    .Select(x => new UserDto
    {
        Id = x.User.Id,
        UserName = x.User.UserName,
        Contact = new ContactDto
        {
            Email = x.Email
        }
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think you need to define what the expected behavior of your expression generator would be for different anonymous types. Would you always be expecting an "Address" property, so that you could set it to "X", for example?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, some entities have one to many relationship to `Contact` table, the constant "X" will be replaced by another selector expression that I have built to replace `user.Contacts.Where(c => c.Type == "Address").Select(x => x.Text).FirstOrDefault()`, I used constant to simplify the problem, so the expected result will always contain property like Address, Phone, Email. I hope this helper can accept the parameter of Principal type (User, Customer, etc) and the type of Contacts we want to extract. But at the moment I'm stuck of replacing `u => new { User = u }` with expression.

Comment: Materialize first. Use dynamic select after? `var arr = context.Set<User>().ToArray().Select(DynamicSelect<...>(...))`

Comment: @B0Andrew, well that means all contacts need to be loaded first, I want to convert the `Contacts` collection navigation property into string of Address, string of Phone, string of Email, etc, and that process should be done in the database

Comment: Could you update your question with more information about the problem you're trying to solve? This will help, both to make it more clear what you expect this method to do *and* give people an opportunity to suggest different solutions. I can think of three approaches that *might* work, but I don't understand your need enough to put together a decent answer.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I have updated the question, but it's solved already, appreciate for the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I compare your expression with the one created by the compiler for something like `u => new { User = u, Address = "X", Fax = "Y" }`, the difference is that the latter has filled `Members`.

I don't quite understand what is the reason for `Members` to exist at all, but I would try to set it, my guess is that it will fix your problem. The code might look something like:

```
var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments);

var newExpression = Expression.New(
    constructor,
    new Expression[] { userParam, Expression.Constant("X"), Expression.Constant("Y") },
    constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p.Name)));
```